# Replace Keybinding In Text Field With Existing Action

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, text

I have a `JTextPane`. I want my own behavior for `Ctrl+Arrow` presses.

```
jTextEntryPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx()), Controls.UP_ACTION);
jTextEntryPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx()), Controls.DOWN_ACTION);
jTextEntryPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx()), Controls.LEFT_ACTION);
jTextEntryPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx()), Controls.RIGHT_ACTION);
jTextEntryPane.getActionMap().put(Controls.UP_ACTION, new MoveAction(Controls.UP_ACTION, this));
jTextEntryPane.getActionMap().put(Controls.DOWN_ACTION, new MoveAction(Controls.DOWN_ACTION, this));
jTextEntryPane.getActionMap().put(Controls.LEFT_ACTION, new MoveAction(Controls.LEFT_ACTION, this));
jTextEntryPane.getActionMap().put(Controls.RIGHT_ACTION, new MoveAction(Controls.RIGHT_ACTION, this));
```

`Ctrl+Up` and `Ctrl+Down` work.

`Ctrl+Left` and `Ctrl+Right` do not, but instead are being used by the text field (to go to the beginning or end of the input field). I want to replace their behavior, but **I do not want to change the regular arrow (left and right) behavior.** How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down are currently not defined as key bindings for the text field so you are just adding new bindings, which is why they work.

However, Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right are already defined as bindings for a JTextField. They are defined for the `WHEN_FOCUSED` InputMap which has priority over the `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` InputMap.

```
jTextEntryPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)....
```

You are using the wrong InputMap for all your bindings.

You should be using:

```
jTextEntryPane.getInputMap()....
```

which will use the `WHEN_FOCUSED` InputMap.

This will allow you to replace the default Action.

See [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a simple program that displays all the default bindings for each component.

Edit:

Tabbing is not handled by the Key Bindings. It is handled by the focus subsystem, so the event is intercepted before it gets to the text field. I believe the following should work:

```
textField.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null);
textField.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have another question. I'd like to do the same with Tab, but it's not working. `jTextEntryPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED), "pressedAction"); jTextEntryPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED),releasedAction");` doesn't trigger the corresponding action. Should I create another question, or edit it into this one?

Comment: @EternalAmbiguity, see edit. If it doesn't help then yes it should be a separate question.